# Show a WinForms from a Console application

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have an existing `Console Application` project.

I have added a `Windows Form` to the project called `myForm`

When the project runs it goes to the Console's `Main` method - in this method how do I activate/show `myForm` ?

I assume I need to import the library `System.Windows.Forms` so the top of my console code looks like the following:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        myForm.    '<<<<not sure how to activate form
        ...
```

Comment: This question lacks research effort.

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen thanks for being honest and adding a comment (I upped it) to go with your down-vote. I was doing a first course in `VB.Net` at the time of posting the question - hence it's naivety.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the reference `System.Windows.Forms`, and then show the form:

```
myForm.Show()
```

Or

```
myForm.ShowDialog()
```

`myForm` has to be a `Form` type. Maybe you need to instanciate you form first:

```
Dim myForm as new FormName
```

Comment: I initially thought it'd be `Show()` but that isn't included in the intellisense ...hence the question. If I type `Show` I get the following `Reference to a non-shared member requires and object reference`

Comment: If its a Form you can use that method. Try it yourself. `Dim frm as New Form()` and try `.ShowDialog` for example. Maybe you have to instanciate your form first.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```vb
Sub Main()
    'Your code goes here...
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(New myForm)
    'Your code goes here...
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Call this function.

```
Application.Run(myForm)
```

It runs even from the console app.

From the documentation,

> Begins running a standard application message loop on the current thread, and makes the specified form visible.

EDIT: Declare it like this.

```
Public Class MyForm
    Inherits Form

    ' Make the code here

End Class
```

```
Dim form As MyForm = New MyForm
Application.Run(form)
```

Comment: if I implement this solution `myForm` gets a wavey line in the `IDE` with message `'myForm' is a type and cannot be used as an expression`

Comment: @whytheq changed the example to vb.net

Comment: I didn't know much about .NET but I use this to show windows. It's the code found in `Program.cs` file created by IDE when I created a `Windows Application`.

Answer (score 1):

No need to import the forms library (**I've tested**) and the working code that I now have is:

My main problem was not declaring and creating an instance of the windows form.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim xForm As myForm = New myForm 
        xForm.ShowDialog()
```